# Create method get by name for list

Tags: java, oop

I have the following class and that provide entity name with key and val of `HashMap`:

```
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;

public class ObjectStructure {
private String entityName;
private LinkedHashMap<String, String> keyVal;

public String getEntityName() {
    return entityName;
}

public void setEntityName(String entityName) {
    this.entityName = entityName;
}

public LinkedHashMap<String, String> getKeyVal() {
    return keyVal;
}

public void setKeyVal(LinkedHashMap<String, String> keyVal) {
    this.keyVal = keyVal;
}
```

}

I have also list as follows

```
private static List<ObjectStructure> JsonObj = new ArrayList<ObjectStructure>();
```

Since I'm getting the `JSON` object which list I need method that provide list by name
(i.e. `entityName` can have many entries and I want for **specific entity** get 
the list of the respective data). I guess I need to build new class for it but I'm not sure how to design it, any ideas?

Comment: What is JObjectStructure?

Comment: edited - should be ObjectStructure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could work with a different map:

```
Map<String, Map<String,String>> entities;
```

The key of the outer map would be the entityName, the inner Map is the collection of key/value pairs. To get the key/value pairs for a named entity, simply do:

```
Map<String, String> keyValueMap = entities.get("MyEntity");
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure what you are asking,
but if your asking how to return a certain `ObjectStructure` by entityName from the arraylist,
then just loop through the `ArrayList` and compare your `searchString` with each `ObjectStructure`'s `entityName`.

If your looking for a value inside of the `ObjectStructure` inside of the `ArrayList` then
search the `ArrayList` for the right `ObjectStructure`. Once found, search the `ObjectStructure` for the key you are looking for.

Comment: thanks but this is not what i meant ,I need the entity from the list json object and I  guess i need to create new class for it with method get entity by name,but im not sure how to define it

Comment: In your code above, your trying to access a `entityName` from a specific `ObjectStructure` in the `JsonObj`?